# Scale text in a grid/viewbox upon pinching

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, pixelsense

For a day now I'm struggling to solving this issue, regarding scaling a textblock and a textbox upon pinching the scatterViewItem for resizing it. 
I've tried putting each of the elements in their viewbox, but also having the whole grid in a viewbox. 
The issue is that it(the textbloxk, that is) doesn't scale upon pinching or stretching rather, (dynamically so to speak) - at runtime, or not even upon contact_up.

Comment: Huh? What do you mean by "upon pinching the scatterViewItem for resizing it"? I get the impression you want something to happen when you pinch something, but it is unclear what. What do you mean by "(dynamically so to speak)"? What do you mean by "having the whole grid in a text box"? Also, what is the question? (You don't seem to actually ask a question here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What actually solves it is simply setting an event handler that fires upon size_changed of the  SVI, inside simply paste the code:

```
{label name}.FontSize *= (double)e.NewSize.Height / (double)e.PreviousSize.Height;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you mean that the TextBlock in the window does not scale when resizing the window...? Have you tried putting a `ViewBox` in a `Grid` that contains the item you want to resize? If you have the item in a `ViewBox`, and set the `Height` and `Width` of the `ViewBox` to `Auto`, is should resize with the window...I hope this helps a little.